# CreateProcess for the current executable in presence of renames

Tags: winapi, createprocess

Is it possible in Windows 10 to call `CreateProcess()` and ensure that it starts exactly the same executable as the current process even if the current executable can be renamed at any moment? For example, if the executable for the current process was originally called `name.exe` but then, while the process was running it was renamed to `name_old.exe`, the child process should use `name_old.exe`?

I can detect the name change of the current process using `QueryFullProcessImageName()`. The trouble is that this is not atomic as the rename can happen exactly between that call and `CreateProcess`.

The background for this is that we are implementing a live update for our application. The update process, when it detects that the application executable is in use, renames the executable to `name_old.exe` and then copies the new version as `name.exe`. Then, when a user closes the last instance of the application using `name_old.exe`, the old version is removed.

This almost works. The trouble is that the application starts child worker processes. Those should use exactly the same executable as the main application as an update can change the protocol of parent-child interaction. So we must prevent the situation when the child uses a new executable while the parent uses the old one.

Comment: If your communication protocol allows for breaking changes, why is there no versioning scheme implemented? That seems to be the real problem you are trying to work around.

Comment: Versioning a protocol for a strictly local IPC is vastly more complex than ensuring that live updates work. In the worst case we may add some communication between the update process and the main application if we do not find a way to resolve the issue without that.

Comment: Odd. You don't know how to solve a particular problem, but are convinced that its solution is less complex than the solution to a solved problem.

Comment: We do know how to create a workaround. For example, the update process can send an event to the app that it is about to rename the executable and wait for the app to acknowledge it, then rename the executable. The app upon receiving the signal then waits until the executable is renamed before creating new child processes. But this requires cooperation between the updater and the app which makes the update process less robust.

Answer (score 0):

Answering own question with a solution that works in our case of a single possible rename into a known name. The trick is to use `CreateProcess()` with `CREATE_SUSPENDED` flag. Then check presence of `name_old.exe`. If the file does not exist, we know there were no renames and we can resume the just created process. If there is this name, we just kill the created process and use CreateProcess with ``name_old.exe` as an executable.

Initially I thought a variation of the above could also work with arbitrary renames. The idea was to use first `QueryFullProcessImageName()` to find the current name of the parent executable, then create as above a suspended child process with that name, then use `QueryFullProcessImageName()` to find again the path of the parent process. If it matches the original, then supposedly there were no renames between the calls and one can resume the child. On mismatch kill the child and repeat.

But that does not work if one allows truly arbitrary renames. For example, a parent can be renamed, the a temporary executable is created under the old name, then the temporary is renamed into yet another name and the parent is renamed back into the original name.